# Umbraco error in Document Types

Tags: templates, umbraco

A long time ago I first setup a website in Umbraco. This seemed to be working fine.
I have now come back to it about a year later, and was initially getting the following error when selecting a Document Type (any document type in the Settings tab):

[image: yellow screen of death]

A bit weird, because earlier I didn't have this issue, but fine. I do what it says, and add `<identity impersonate="true"/>` to the `<system.web>` node in web.config.

While it does fix the initial issue, I now have the following on all document types:

[image: 404 page]

When trying to create a new Document Type, I get the same kind of error, but then the ReturnUrl part is `ReturnUrl=/umbraco/create.aspx?nodeId=init&nodeType=inittemplates&nodeName=Templates&rnd=20.2&rndo=21.2&nodeId=init&nodeType=inittemplates&nodeName=Templates&rnd=20.2&rndo=21.2'` - but only if I tick the box 'Create template for this item'. The same happens when I try and create a Template.

After Googleing I came up with this: [our.umbraco post with similar issue](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/17351-Template-problem-%28-!!Help-please). One (unconfirmed) solution is that there's an illegal name in a document type/ template - but I haven't changed anything, and might be fixed by going into the database. 
I did check the /masterpages folder, the only 'strange' characters in there are - and _. 
In my Document Types I have on named 'Textpage (Two col)' and another named 'News & Events list'. I'm a bit hesitant to just delete them, since I don't have enough Umbraco knoledge to be sure this will fix my issue...

Is there any known solution for this, or will I also have to go into the database (and if so, whereabouts?)

I'm running Umbraco 4.7.2, assembly version 1.0.4500.21031.
I've hosted this site with GoDaddy.com - I don't know if that would be relevant.

**[Update 1]** 
As per Tom Maton's comment:

The requirepermissions should be set to false, and have been.

in Appsettings I've set this:

```
<add key="umbracoUseMediumTrust" value="true" />
```

And I've added `Trusted_Connection=yes` to the connectionstring. 
the problem remains.

**[Update 2]**
Tried the solution amelvin provided, but no dice. Doctypes and templates still give the error. I'm getting more certain it's some security issues. Which folder would correspond to the Templates? Would that be the masterpages folder? If so, what kind of permissions does that one need?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you don't have full trust on your Go Daddy environment?

Check this post out http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/17856-Umbraco-on-GoDaddy-Shared-Hosting

Could help resolve your issue.

Comment: This is something I looked at earlier as well when I was setting it up initially. I have the requirepermissions, useinmediumtrust and usetrustedconnection set up , but no dice.
I added it to the question as well.

I have asked GoDaddy support as well, but no response yet..

Answer (score 1):

The error could be a knock on from permissions errors as yet unsolved.

But the error is thrown if the content page does not have a template assigned or if Umbraco thinks it doesn't have a template.  If absolutely nothing has changed to the site then it could be that the umbraco.config file has somehow got corrupted (it will contain all the doctype/template cross reference info).  This can be fixed by right clicking on the top 'content' node and choose 'republish entire website'.

Secondly navigate to the settings | document types (if you can now) and check the templates dropdown on the first tab of the appropriate document type.  If its set to 'please select' then this error will get thrown when any page tries to render without a valid template assigned.  If a default template is assigned - then go to that template and re-publish it - Umbraco may have lost it.

If this does not work then check if the template is assigned properly.  Go to the same place in the content tree as the problem page and try to add a node with the desired doctype.  If no choices are offered then it could be that the parent tab no longer allows the correct doctypes as children nodes, so go back to the doctypes and check the allowed children (second tab) of the parent node.

If none of this works without odd errors being thrown then its a mystery!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll not be able to try this until tonight. I'll definitely update after that. 

I hadn't specified in the original question, but the front-end of the website works fine, as well as all other back-end functionality. (as far as I've been able to tell)

Comment: @amelvin, you are brilliant!!! you question solved my big headache. and the "re-public" fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here are a list of Permissions required for Umbraco http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/permissions

Or you could use one of the steps below to check all the folder permissions.

1. http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/permissions/perform-permissions-check
2. Or install this package. http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/ugolive this will allow you to check the permissions are correctly setup.

Comment: Brilliant stuff! +1, as this will make my life a lot easier figuring this issue out :-)